# Can I reach Global Address List language independently?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation, gal

I would like to create an excel tool which at some point of the operation opens the Global Address List of the Outlook. I have figured it out how to do this, but there was an issue when we tried it on a German languaged computer. I have solved it by check the UI language prior to opening the address book, but I wondered if there is a language independent way to do so? (So I don't need to create a case for every possible languages.) 
My corresponding code portion is:

```
langCode=Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
Select Case langCode
 Case &H409
  galStr="Global Address List"
 Case &H40E
  galStr="Globális címlista"
 Case &H407
  galStr="Globale Addressliste"
 Case Else
  galStr="Global Address List"
End Select 

Set olApp=GetObject(,"Outlook.Application")

Set olGAL=olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"). AddressLists(galStr)
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your end goal? Why do you need to get the address list for GAL?

Comment: Hi, I get the users e-mail address from the GAL, whom the entry will be dedicated. They at the end will get an automatic e-mail. The GAL contains every one at the company worldwide, that's why I use it.

Comment: Have you considered using the `CreateRecipient` method instead of relying on the GAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Namespace.`[GetGlobalAddressList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getglobaladdresslist) - it will return the GAL of the primary Exchange account in the profile.

As for the `AddrList.AddressListType` property, it will return `olExchangeGlobalAddressList` only for the GAL of the primary Exchange account. For a secondary account, it will be a generic `olExchangeContainer`.

If you have more than one Exchange account in the profile, you can figure out if a particular address list is GAL by reading two MAPI properties using `AddressList.PropertyAccessor`: `PR_AB_PROVIDER_ID` must be `"DCA740C8C042101AB4B908002B2FE182"`and `PR_DISPLAY_TYPE` must be `DT_GLOBAL` (`0x00020000`).

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, besides exposing `RDOSession`.[Addressbook](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm).`GAL` (similar to `Namespace.GetGlobalAddressList` in OOM), it also exposes [RDOExchangeAccount](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm#RDOExchangeAccount).`GAL` property on the account level (`AllRooms` property is also exposed).

Comment: Hello, thak you the help, it is working very well. It is an easy and clear solution! I wonder why the most of the examples on the net are not using this method...

Answer (score 0):

For user language and programming language independence there is enumeration.

[OlAddressListType enumeration (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/vba/api/outlook.oladdresslisttype)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find the correct localized sting you may iterate over all address lists and get the GAL in the following way:

```
If(addrList.AddressListType ==
            Outlook.OlAddressListType.olExchangeGlobalAddressList) Then
 ' this is GAL
End If
```

You can use the [NameSpace.CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) function which creates a `Recipient` object. After [resolving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) a recipient against the address book you may get the email address.

Also I've found the following article - [Get the Global Address List or a set of address lists for a store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-the-global-address-list-or-a-set-of-address-lists-for-a-store) which you may find helpful.

Comment: Hello, thank you the help. Iterating through the address lists is worked fine but Dmitry's solution is more straightforward by referencing directly the GAL.